# Multisite Super admin and Network admin emails

Tags: multisite

I have a Wordpress multisite.

I would like to change the email address on the super admin account.

The current email address on the super admin account is no longer accessible.

I can change the Network Admin Email in Network Settings but if I try to change the super admin email in users > profile I get a message saying 'There is a pending change of your email'

Do I need access to the old email address on the super admin account to confirm the change of email address.

Comment: Why not do this through phpmyadmin or similar SQL editor?

Comment: Can I just change the value in phpMyAdmin without causing any problems in the front end

Answer (score 2):

The network admin email is changed from wp_sitemeta table. Use following query in phpmyadmin or any mysql client in order to update the email if you are unable to change from network admin settings.

```
UPDATE `wp_sitemeta` SET `meta_value` = 'the_new_email@abc.com' WHERE `meta_value` = 'the_old_email@abc.com';
```

Note: please use the table prefix accordingly used in db if it is not wp in your case.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The question is old. However, I would like to answer it in the most effective way, as it can help a lot of people.

You can change the email address on the super admin account through phpmyadmin. Follow these steps:

1. Sign into your cPanel account, which is provided by your web hosting.
2. Under database section, click on the **phpMyAdmin** icon.
3. A new page will appear. From the left-hand sidebar, click on your
   database name.
4. A list of database tables will be displayed. Click on
   **wp_options**.
5. You will see a new page. Find "**admin_email**" under
   "**option_name**. You will see your current admin email address in
   the "**option_value**" column. Click on **Edit**.
6. A white box containing your current email address will appear. Type
   your new email address. Finally, click on the **Go** button to save it.
   [image]

You will find more information about these steps [right here](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-change-the-wordpress-admin-email-address-from-phpmyadmin-using-cpanel/). If you follow them accordingly, you will be able to change the email address on the super admin account successfully.

Comment: This is incorrect, it's actually in the `wp_sitemeta` table for Multisite.